# Delete X lines after and Y lines before matching line

Tags: text-processing, freebsd

I have the following string:

```
core1@pci0:2:0:1:  class=0x020000 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00 vendor=0x1453
    vendor     = 'MicSystem'
    device     = 'controller'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ethernet
none65@pci0:2:0:2:      class=0x080100 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00 vendor=0x1453
    vendor     = 'MicSystem'
    device     = 'interface'
    class      = base peripheral
    subclass   = DMA controller
core1@pci0:2:0:1:  class=0x020000 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00 vendor=0x1453
    vendor     = 'MicSystem'
    device     = 'controller'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ethernet
```

I have to remove 3 lines before and 1 line after where 'class = base peripheral', for example:

```
core1@pci0:2:0:1:  class=0x020000 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00 vendor=0x1453
    vendor     = 'MicSystem'
    device     = 'controller'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ethernet
core1@pci0:2:0:1:  class=0x020000 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00 vendor=0x1453 
    vendor     = 'MicSystem'
    device     = 'controller'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ethernet
```

I didn't manage to do that, this is done in FreeBSD OS.

Comment: What if there are multiple matches of the target string? Should it delete only the first block or all the blocks?

Comment: @Quasímodo all the blocks that contain 'base peripheral. there is an option to do that without using file?

Answer (score 5):

Actually use [Ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) or [Ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html):

```
ed -s file <<EOF
g/base peripheral/-3;+4d
%p
EOF
```

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/base peripheral/-3;+4d' '%p' | ex -s file
```

The `g`lobal marks all lines with "base peripheral" and `d`eletes the given range. Then `%p` prints the file. You can use `w` to save the changes to the file instead.

Comment: I should look more into `ed` ... Nice answer.

Comment: There is an option to do that without using file?

Comment: @ItayAvraham You mean that is the output of a command? In a capable shell you could use process substitution, i.e. do `printf '%s\n' 'g/base peripheral/-3;+4d' '%p' | ex -s <(command)`. Please [edit] your question to clarify all the points raised here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `awk`:

```bsh
awk '
FNR==NR && /class[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*base peripheral/{x=NR; nextfile;}
FNR!=NR && (FNR < x-3 || FNR > x+1)
' file file
```

Feeds `file` twice into `awk`. First time, find the relevant line (only the first match if there are multiple!). Second time, print the lines excluding the lines you want to omit.

To use with command output, use:

```bsh
awk '...' <(command) <(command)
```

or

```bsh
output="$(command)"
awk '...' <(printf '%s' "$output") <(printf '%s' "$output")
```

Comment: There is an option to do that without using file?

Comment: You can try  `awk '...' <(command) <(command)` or `output="$(command)"; awk '...' <(printf '%s' "$output") <(printf '%s' "$output")`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is probably the following, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$0 ~ re {
    for (i=(NR-b); i<=(NR+a); i++) {
        skip[i]
    }
}
{ lines[NR] = $0 }
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
        if ( !(i in skip) ) {
            print lines[i]
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v b=3 -v a=1 -v re='class[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*base peripheral' -f tst.awk file
    core1@pci0:2:0:1:  class=0x020000 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00 vendor=0x1453 device=0xa2d2 subvendor=0x1453 subdevice=0x0008
        vendor     = 'MicSystem'
        device     = 'controller'
        class      = network
        subclass   = ethernet
    core1@pci0:2:0:1:  class=0x020000 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00 vendor=0x1453 device=0xa2d2 subvendor=0x1453 subdevice=0x0008
            vendor     = 'MicSystem'
            device     = 'controller'
            class      = network
            subclass   = ethernet
```

If your input is coming from a pipe instead of stored in a shell then just do `whatever | awk -v ... -f tst.awk` or whatever else it is you usually do to pass input to a script.

Like the `ed` solution the above reads the whole input into memory but that won't be a problem if your input isn't hundreds of millions of lines long. If you do have that case then you could implement a rolling buffer that's an array of size `b` so you always print the 1st element from that array when the current line doesn't match the regexp but that requires a bit more thought to write and makes handling overlapping ranges harder.

Answer (score 0):

Using the utility `perl`, we can do as shown:-

```
perl -le '
  print shift =~
    s/(?:.*\n){3}
      (?-x:.*base peripheral.*\n)
      (?:.*\n){1}
    //rxg;
' "$str"
```

---

Stream editor `GNU sed`  with default printing of pattern space OFF `-n` :-

```
printf '%s\n' "$str" |
sed -n '
  1N;2N;$!N
  /\n[^\n]*base peripheral[^\n]*$/!{P;D;}
  n' -
```

Three lines before the match line, one line after the match line, and the match line, all are clipped from the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Although the problem is being described in terms of delete so many lines before this line and after that line, it is obvious that the effect of these intended edits has a higher level meaning "remove the item whose `class` property has the value `base peripheral`".

There is an ideally suitable language for these kinds of transformation tasks where we heed the larger document structure: [TXR](https://www.nongnu.org/txr).

We can do a detailed job of extracting the fields, with code that is easy to understand by someone else, or yourself 17 months later:

```
@(repeat)
@addr: class=0x@cl rev=0x@rev hdr=0x@hdr vendor=0x@ven
    vendor     = '@vendor'
    device     = '@device'
    class      = @class
    subclass   = @subclass
@  (require (nequal class "base peripheral"))
@  (output)
@addr: class=0x@cl rev=0x@rev hdr=0x@hdr vendor=0x@ven
    vendor     = '@vendor'
    device     = '@device'
    class      = @class
    subclass   = @subclass
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr data.txr data
core1@pci0:2:0:1: class=0x020000 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00 vendor=0x1453
    vendor     = 'MicSystem'
    device     = 'controller'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ethernet
core1@pci0:2:0:1: class=0x020000 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00 vendor=0x1453
    vendor     = 'MicSystem'
    device     = 'controller'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ethernet
```

Here, the pattern matching assertion `@(require expr)` is what eliminates the unwanted item; it fails when `expr` is false.

You can make the filtering arbitrarily complex, and easily reshape the output however you want. The embedded TXR Lisp language has magic super-powers also.